# Multiple locks of one method from multiple objects

Tags: .net, multithreading, synchronization

I came across the following question: if we have, for example, 2 methods from 2 different classes and both of them are using one DAL and every method has a lock statement when using the same method from the DAL, but the lock to a different objects, internal for each class. So my question is: Are the calls to the DAL still going to be synchronized?

Comment: Removed "C" tag, do you mean "c#"? C isn't a .NET language...

Comment: It's unclear. If you need to make a method thread safe, the locks should be in the method. Locking externally will result in tears and recriminations.

Comment: The locks are not internal, the method is locked from the outside, for example from 2 differente classes.